# Facebook OpenGraph API errors on user id lookup

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

Fairly simple task right?

http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola    returns the  ID

http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305 returns Cocacola

So I have an enigma.

http://graph.facebook.com/tacobell.careers   renturns  false

http://graph.facebook.com/38614264036 returns false (this is the only ID could find)

http://facebook.com/tacobell.careers  does exist and pulls a page up. It has Likes and not friends so it IS a PAGE.

Can anyone find the ID and get a valid object back from openGraph API?

Thank you very much.  Please enlighten me as to how you did it so I can do it in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo but has no bearing on the question. Anyone have any clue at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a closed-by-design [Facebook bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18162) about this.  That page has demographic restrictions enabled on it.  I was able to access that page using the graph api if I specify an access_token. For example, go to this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and click on one of the sample url's that use an access_token (like friends).  Then change the url to tacobell.careers, leaving the access_token.

Comment: Yay! Thanks. Now I am battling the oAuth... THANKS TONS FOR YOUR HELP!!